# Create a variable by assigning a sequence to each id R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, seq

I have this column from a dataframe with Ids:

```
id
1
3
9
12
11
```

The ids don´t repeat in the dataframe. I´m trying to creating a new dataframe assigning a sequence `c(-1:1)` for each id. I´m trying to get something like this:

```
id   seqvalue
1  -1
1   0
1   1
3   -1
3   0
3   1
9   -1
9   0
9   1
12   -1
12   0
12   1
11   -1
11   0
11   1
```

Comment: Perhaps just something like `data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 3, 9, 12, 11), each = length(-1:1)), seqvalue = -1:1)`?

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot. I was trying with a loop but this is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Use `expand.grid` like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(id = c(1, 3, 9, 12))
expand.grid(seqvalue = seq(-1, 1), id = DF$id)[2:1]
```

**2)** Another possibility is `merge`:

```
merge(data.frame(seqvalue = seq(-1, 1)), DF)[2:1]
```